# Algorithm to sort an array

Tags: algorithms

I tried to apply the following Counting Sort algorithm at an example with array $$A=\langle 6, 0, 2, 0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 1, 3, 2 \rangle$$

```
COUNTING_SORT (A, B, k)

for i ← 1 to k do
    c[i] ← 0
for j ← 1 to n do
    c[A[j]] ← c[A[j]] + 1
//c[i] now contains the number of elements equal to i
for i ← 2 to k do
    c[i] ← c[i] + c[i-1]
// c[i] now contains the number of elements ≤ i
for j ← n downto 1 do
    B[c[A[i]]] ← A[j]
    c[A[i]] ← c[A[j]] - 1
```

The resulting array that I got is the following:

$$B= | \ \ \cdot \ \ |\  0 \ |\  0 \ |\  1 \ |\  2 \ |\  2 \ |\  3 \ |\  3 \ |\  4 \ | \ \ \cdot \ \ | 6$$

So, two positions of the array $B$ are still empty... Why does this happen??

Comment: Seems like a more appropriate question for http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't think this fits with `cstheory` (which is actually more akin to MathOverflow).  Note that duplicate entries for 1 and 6 are missing.  To ask help to debug an algorithm (as in debugging software) one wants to have a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/487781).

Comment: The `c` array must go from `c[0]` to `c[6]`, not from `c[1]` to `c[6]`.

Comment: Ok... Thanks!! :-) @TonyK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several problems. First, your keys range from $0$ through $6$, so if `k` is the maximum key (here $6$), the first line should be:

```
for i ← 0 to k
```

After completion of the first two loops your `c` array will read $\langle 2,2,2,2,1,0,2\rangle$, and the comment that follows the second loop will be correct: `c[0]` contains $2$, the number of elements equal to $0$, and so on. The third loop should then start at $1$:

```
for i ← 1 to k
```

When it completes, the `c` array will read $\langle 2,4,6,8,9,9,11\rangle$, and `c[i]` will indeed contain the number of elements less than or equal to `i`.

The `i` in the last two lines is undefined; it should be `j`, so that the loop reads:

```
for j ← n downto 1 do  
    B[c[A[j]] ← A[j]  
    c[A[j]] ← c[A[j]] - 1
```

Since `n` is $11$, `A[11]` is $2$, and `c[2]` is $6$ (remember that `c` is $0$-indexed), the first pass through this loop will give you $\langle 0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0\rangle$ for `B` and $\langle 2,4,5,8,9,9,11\rangle$ for `c`.

Now `j` is $10$, `A[10]` is $3$, `c[3]` is $8$, and the next pass through the loop leaves you with $\langle 0,0,0,0,0,2,0,3,0,0,0\rangle$ for `B` and $\langle 2,4,5,7,9,9,11\rangle$ for `c`. Continuing in this fashion, we can fill in the following matrix showing the contents of `B` and `c` at the end of the `j` pass through the loop:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
j&B&c\\ \hline
11&\langle \cdot,\cdot,\cdot,\cdot,\cdot,2,\cdot,\cdot,\cdot,\cdot,\cdot\rangle&\langle 2,4,5,8,9,9,11\rangle\\
10&\langle \cdot,\cdot,\cdot,\cdot,\cdot,2,\cdot,3,\cdot,\cdot,\cdot\rangle&\langle 2,4,5,7,9,9,11\rangle\\
9&\langle \cdot,\cdot,\cdot,1,\cdot,2,\cdot,3,\cdot,\cdot,\cdot\rangle&\langle 2,3,5,7,9,9,11\rangle\\
8&\langle \cdot,\cdot,\cdot,1,\cdot,2,\cdot,3,\cdot,\cdot,6\rangle&\langle 2,3,5,7,9,9,10\rangle\\
7&\langle \cdot,\cdot,\cdot,1,\cdot,2,\cdot,3,4,\cdot,6\rangle&\langle 2,3,5,7,8,9,10\rangle\\
6&\langle \cdot,\cdot,\cdot,1,\cdot,2,3,3,4,\cdot,6\rangle&\langle 2,3,5,6,8,9,10\rangle\\
5&\langle \cdot,\cdot,1,1,\cdot,2,3,3,4,\cdot,6\rangle&\langle 2,2,5,6,8,9,10\rangle\\
4&\langle \cdot,0,1,1,\cdot,2,3,3,4,\cdot,6\rangle&\langle 1,2,5,6,8,9,10\rangle\\
3&\langle \cdot,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,\cdot,6\rangle&\langle 1,2,4,6,8,9,10\rangle\\
2&\langle 0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,\cdot,6\rangle&\langle 0,2,4,6,8,9,10\rangle\\
2&\langle 0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,6,6\rangle&\langle 0,2,4,6,8,9,9\rangle\\
\end{array}$$

I’ve used the character $\cdot$ instead of $0$ for cells of `B` that have not yet been filled with output so as to make it easy to distinguish them from cells filled with $0$.

Comment: I see... Thank you very much!!! :-) 

$$$$ 

The exercise that I am looking at asks to describe the operation of CountingSort at the array $A=\langle 6, 0, 2, 0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 1, 3, 2 \rangle$. What does it mean to describe the operation?? Beside showing the work of the algorithm as you did , what else do I have to do?? @BrianM.Scott

Comment: Could you take a look at my other question?? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1179564/do-i-have-to-apply-an-algorithm-or-just-compare-them

Comment: What could I say to describe the operation of Counting Sort at the array $A$?? @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Mary: Nothing ever happens to `A`: its contents never change. They are used only as pointers to cells in the array `c`. Thus, there’s really nothing to say.

Comment: Ok... Thank you!! :-)

Comment: @Mary: You’re welcome!